# Determine if a commit author is uninitalized

Tags: c++, c, initialization, libgit2

I am trying to use the libgit2 API in my program. I have to traverse through the commits and compare a commit to its parent and I also need the author of each modification. I am testing the program on the Linux kernel, where there are commits whose author is somehow invalid: invoking the `git_commit_author` method does provide a `git_signature` object, but the `name` and `email` fields are uninitialized.

Is there a way, maybe an API call to tell the author is invalid/uninitialized? I already tried using `std::isgraph` to determine if a character in `name` is graphic but it still throws a segfault when the uninitialized field is empty.

```cpp
const git_signature* commitAuthor = git_commit_author(job._commit);

if (commitAuthor && !std::isgraph(commitAuthor->name[0]))  // segfault happens here
    return;
```

Comment: Can't immediately find documentation, but I would guess that `commitAuthor->name` is initialized to a null pointer if the author has no name.  So your test should be `if (commitAuthor && !commitAuthor->name) return; // no name`

Comment: By the way, your tag says [tag:c] but the `std::` is [tag:c++].

Comment: Have you tried stepping into that code with a debugger? It should identify exactly what pointer is causing the segfault. I don't see any verification that git_signature isn't null. I checked [their docs](https://libgit2.org/libgit2/#v0.18.0/group/commit/git_commit_author) and it doesn't say whether `git_commit_author` will or will not return a null pointer.

Comment: @NateEldredge I added the C++ tag, too. @jwdonhaue I already tried stepping in with a debugger. `commitAuthor->name`, if not initialized, is either a `\0` (the suggested condition works in this case) or some garbage value, I guess it's a UB.